# Semantics of abstract traits in Scala

Tags: scala, abstract, traits

I am wondering what the semantics of using the `abstract` keyword in combination with a `trait` is.

If the trait does not define any abstract methods, the `abstract` keyword does not prevent me from creating an instance:

```
scala> abstract trait T
defined trait T

scala> new T{}
res0: java.lang.Object with T = $anon$1@12cd927d
```

On the other hand, if the trait does define an abstract method, I cannot create an instance (without implementing this method of course) no matter if the `abstract` keyword is present or not:

```
scala> abstract trait T { def foo : Unit }
defined trait T

scala> new T{}
<console>:9: error: object creation impossible, since method foo in trait T of type =>    Unit is not defined
              new T{}
                  ^

scala> trait T { def foo : Unit }
defined trait T

scala> new T{}
<console>:9: error: object creation impossible, since method foo in trait T of type =>     Unit is not defined
              new T{}
                  ^
```

So what is the `abstract` keyword in front of a `trait` good for?

Comment: You can't create an instance of a trait. When you say `new T{}` you create an anonymous object which mixins the trait T.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It has no effect, traits are automatically abstract.

> The abstract modifier is used in class definitions. It is redundant
>   for traits, and mandatory for all other classes which have incomplete
>   members.

http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You're not creating an instance of the trait. Traits can't be instantiated.

You're creating an instance of an anonymous class extending the trait.

In general,

```
new __t__
```

is equivalent to

```
{ class __anonymous__ extends __t__; new __anonymous__ }
```

(where `__anonymous__` is a *fresh name* of an anonymous class that is inaccessible to the user program).

This is detailed in [section 6.10 *Instance Creation Expressions* of the Scala Language Specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#instance-creation-expressions).

So, the reason why you can create an instance in the first case, is because you're not creating an instance of the trait (which is abstract) but an object (which isn't).

In the second case, the reason why you can't create an instance is that if you inherit from something, whether that is a trait or a class, you ultimately have to implement its abstract methods somewhere along the inheritance chain in order to instantiate it. In the first case, there are no abstract methods to implement.

The `abstract` keyword itself makes no difference: traits are implicitly abstract, the keyword is redundant.

Comment: I think you mean that he is creating an anonymous *class*, which has the trait as a mixin.

Comment: Sorry, yes. An object that is an instance of an anonymous class that is a subclass of the trait. Phew.