# Case class matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

If someone could explain this behavior in plain english I would really appreciate it. Specifically, is there any difference between `case _:Foo` and `case Foo()`?

```
myvariable match {
  case _: Foo => println("its a foo!")
  case Foo() => println("It's also a Foo")
  case Foo => println("Oops, this will *not* match a Foo! It will never be called")
  case _ => println("This will be called for all unmatched items")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a normal type match, sort of like a instanceOf in Java for example.

```
case x: Foo => ???
```

It guarantees that you can use x as a Foo on the right hand side

```
case Foo(a,b,c) => ???
```

On the other hand tries to call unapply (which you get for free on a case class) and allows you to "reach into" the instance and catch all fields as vals that you can use on the right hand side.

Side note: defining a case class with no fields is essentially identical to using a case object, which is what most people do in Scala to just represent one possible value. So your second case is a bit strange, and would probably rather be done using case objects:

```
case object Foo

case Foo => ???
```

Comment: Ahhh I get it now, `case Foo()` is actually calling `Foo.unapply`, but because it's an empty parameter list there's nothing to extract. I know the third case is a bit odd, but I think it's a common mistake so I wanted to include it as an "oops" for others reading

Comment: @Hamy The third case is not odd at all -- you do this when you want to match a *value*, rather than a structure. So if you have a case of a `sealed trait` that doesn't carry any data, as johanandren alluded to, you could make it a `case object` and match it that way. You can also match literal values that way too. There's another type of case too which uses backticks to match against a previously defined variable.

Comment: @acjay - Sure, all great advice. Perhaps odd was the wrong word, I meant that I believe people often confuse `case Foo` with `case Foo()`, not realizing that the former is probably not doing what they intended. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254710/why-were-the-case-classes-without-a-parameter-list-deprecated where the first answer mentions this confusion