# Scala/IntelliJ: case object X vs case class X vs case class X()

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, case-class

There are case classes in Scala:

```
case class X(one: One, two: two)
```

There are case objects which have only one instance (which makes sense):

```
case object X
```

When I declare a case class without parameters, IntelliJ does the right thing and deprecation-warns me to make it a case object:

```
case class X // deprecated stuff
```

However it does not warn me about

```
case class X()
```

Which makes me wonder whether there is a difference between `case class X` and `case class X()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what Scala version you are using, but in 2.11 this is not only deprecated but indeed an error:

```
 Error:(34, 17) case classes without a parameter list are not allowed;
 use either case objects or case classes with an explicit `()' 
 as a parameter list.
   case class Foo
                 ^
```

Simply, you cannot pattern match against a no-parameter-list case class, so there is no use for them.

```
case class Foo()

def test(in: Any) = in match {
  case Foo() => "foo"
  case _     => "other"
}
```

Comment: I have to admit that I do not properly distinguish between warnings in errors in eclipse. It starts barking at me, I do something :-)

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a case object, only a single instance is ever created. However, you can have multiple different instances of a no-param case class. Why you might want that is a different matter.

In principle, there is no difference between `case class Foo` and `case class Foo()`. I think the former was deprecated because of how easy it is to inadvertently misuse it. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2254961/5519149) illustrates the point nicely.